How to save corrupted PBIX file with PowerBI error Vertipaq?
Kind people on here,
my classmate just tried to open his PBIX file after restarting his laptop. His end project needs to turned in in about 36 hours and the file seems to be corrupted.
I searched around a lot, asked GPT for tips and tricks, but none of them do the trick (emptying cache, upgrading powerBI).
The trick to zip it and delete the datamodel makes it open again, but that will implicate that he has to do ALL of the data cleaning again and built the model again from scratch. Almost impossible.
There doesn't seem to be a hotfix for it.
Is there someone who can save my friend and thus his grades? Any suggestion could be helpfull. Your help would REALLY be appreciated. THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE!!!
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)
Timestamp:
2024-12-19T13:38:15.5067166Z
Local Time:
2024-12-19T14:38:15.5067166+01:00
Session ID:
e17758b0-c712-405a-adfc-accb492ce844
Release:
September 2024
Product Version:
2.136.1478.0 (24.09) (x64)
Error Message:
Database consistency checks (DBCC) failed while checking the string store.
An error occurred while loading Vertipaq data objects for multiple tables.
Stack Trace:
Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Storage.FileOpenException
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.LocalAnalysisServicesDatabaseCreator.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.AnalysisServicesDatabaseCreatorFactory.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.PowerBIPackagingService.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.BiPackageOperationHandler.d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.CurrentArtifactManager.d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.CurrentArtifactManager.<>c_DisplayClass35_0.<b_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.UIBlockingService.<>c_DisplayClass13_01.<b_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.UIBlockingService.WaitOnUIThreadForTaskCompletion[T](Task1 task)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.UIBlockingService.BlockUIAndRun[T](Func1 asyncMethod)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.CurrentArtifactManager.OpenArtifactAndSetAsCurrent(IPowerBIWindowService windowService, IPowerBIArtifact artifactToOpen, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Nullable1 entryPoint)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.CommandLineFileService.TryOpenOrCreateReport(IPowerBIWindowService windowService, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Boolean forceCreate)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c_DisplayClass7_0.b_0()
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c_DisplayClass3_0.b_0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
Stack Trace Message:
Database consistency checks (DBCC) failed while checking the string store.
An error occurred while loading Vertipaq data objects for multiple tables.
Invocation Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.GetStackTraceInfo(Exception e)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c_DisplayClass14_0.b_0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplicationLegacy(String[] args)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
PowerBINonFatalError:
{"AppName":"PBIDesktop","AppVersion":"2.136.1478.0","ModuleName":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.dll","Component":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.LocalAnalysisServicesDatabaseCreator+d__7","Error":"Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Storage.FileOpenException","MethodDef":"MoveNext - PFE_XM_DBCC_STRINGSTORE_CORRUPT,PFE_XM_ERROR_WHILE_PARALLEL_LOADING_IMBI_TABLE_DATA","ErrorOffset":"508","ErrorCode":"DataModelLoadFailed"}
InnerException0.Stack Trace Message:
Database consistency checks (DBCC) failed while checking the string store.
An error occurred while loading Vertipaq data objects for multiple tables.
InnerException0.Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService.ExecuteXmla(String xmla, ITelemetryService telemetryService)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService.ImageLoadDatabaseFromPbix(String databaseName, String filePath, Uri dataModelPath, ITelemetryService telemetryService)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.AnalysisServicesService.LoadDatabaseFromPbix(String filePath, Uri dataModelPath)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Services.LocalAnalysisServicesDatabaseCreator.d__7.MoveNext()
InnerException0.Invocation Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromException(Exception e, String prefix)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.GetFeedbackValuesFromInnerExceptions(Exception e, Int32 depth)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo.CreateAdditionalErrorInfo(Exception e)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c_DisplayClass14_0.b_0()
at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.PowerBIUnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.RunApplicationLegacy(String[] args)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
OS Version:
Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.22631.0 (x64 en-US)
CLR Version:
4.8 or later [Release Number = 533320]
Peak Virtual Memory:
70.2 GB
Private Memory:
293 MB
Peak Working Set:
728 MB
IE Version:
11.1.22621.0
User ID:
5c179af6-fae7-43fa-8740-398a2edd040a
Telemetry Enabled:
True
PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorCode:
DataModelLoadFailed
PowerBINonFatalError_MethodDefDescription:
PFE_XM_DBCC_STRINGSTORE_CORRUPT,PFE_XM_ERROR_WHILE_PARALLEL_LOADING_IMBI_TABLE_DATA
PowerBIUserFeedbackServices_IsReported:
True
InnerException0.PowerBINonFatalError_ErrorDescription:
PFE_XM_DBCC_STRINGSTORE_CORRUPT,PFE_XM_ERROR_WHILE_PARALLEL_LOADING_IMBI_TABLE_DATA
InnerException0.PowerBINonFatalError_MethodDefDescription:
PFE_XM_DBCC_STRINGSTORE_CORRUPT,PFE_XM_ERROR_WHILE_PARALLEL_LOADING_IMBI_TABLE_DATA
DPI Scale:
125%
Supported Services:
Power BI
(emptying cache, upgrading powerBI).
The trick to zip it and delete the datamodel makes it open again, but that will implicate that he has to do ALL of the data cleaning again and built the model again from scratch. Almost impossible.

According to the error message, an issue occurred while loading VertiPaq data objects for multiple tables. This indicates that the file is corrupted and cannot be repaired.
One thing i'd try is to install the latest version of Power BI Desktop and try opening the file again.
